# select option of select group?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have got two select with classes ,select1 and .select2 and a button with class .btn
Now when both select are clicked then only button color must change.
Can any one help me on this

This must be done using jquery.

Comment: You mean when both select are selected then button color will change?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
$('.select1,.select2').on('change', function(){
   $('.btn').addClass('newClassWithColorChange');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working solution    http://jsfiddle.net/ApfJz/7/

HTML:

```
<select class="select1">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
<select class="select2">
    <option>10</option>
    <option>20</option>
    <option>30</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="mybutton" value="Button" />
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.select1, .select2').change(function(){
        $('#mybutton').css('background-color', 'red'); // here do what you want on dropdown change        
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.select1,.select2').on('change', function(){

   if(!$(this).hasClass('clicked'))
   {
       $(this).addClass("clicked");
   }
    if($("select.clicked").length == 2)
      $('.btn').addClass('newClassWithColorChange');
});
```

Comment: Here you can easily track if both select tag are clicked or not..
and assign class to them .

Is it matching your requirement now?